# Reflecting ionic2 project changes in XCode

Tags: xcode, ionic2

Reflecting new changes of ionic2 project in xcode is a painful process for me.

I tried these commands:

- sudo ionic state restore
- sudo ionic prepare ios

from command line

and tried Product => Clean & rebuild from xcode, but still having the old project

Am using XCode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) on macOS Sierra version 10.12.3

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried by just running `ionic build ios [--prod]`? What do you mean by changes when you say _Reflecting ionic2 project changes in XCode_?

Comment: i mean am coding on NetBeans, and made many changes to my project, but when running the project on emulator or device i get an older version of my work.

Comment: Hmm... If you run `ionic run ios --device --prod` can you see the last version of the app in your device?